# Finding offset of an object file using objdump

Tags: linux, object, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am a bit confused while trying to find the code of an object file in which a particular offset corresponds to. The offset is `0xB71B13E8`

Using `proc/<PID>/maps`, I found out that the text code of the libX11 lib for the target process was mapped on the `0xB70CC000-0xB71B7000` region.

I now want to find this offset on the object file of the X11 lib `/usr/lib/libX11.so.6.2.0` using objdump.

Should I look into `0xB71B7000 - 0xB71B13E8 = 0x5C18` or into `0xB71B13E8 - 0xB70CC000 = 0xE53E8` ?

Another question that I have is the following:
The `0xB70CC000-0xB71B7000` region in which the text code of the libX11 lib resides is of `0xEB000` bytes. However, when I objdump `/usr/lib/libX11.so.6.2.0` I can see offsets starting from `0xA3517 to 0x135C0` (i.e. only `0x8FF57`). Is there any reason for that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The first address of the r-x section in /proc/X/maps (you can use 'pmap X', too) is the first virtual address of the library, while the offsets displayed by objdump --disassemble are the virtual addresses assuming a start of 0. The address you're interested in is 0xE53E8 (assuming the numbers you gave are from looking at the r-x mapping), so look for that address in the objdump --disassemble output to find the correct code location.

Note that you can use gdb to directly look at a running program's memory. Start gdb then run 'attach X' where X is the PID of the running program, then 'disassemble 0xB71B13E8'.